# not all snippet interface links can be selected by the tab key

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, user-interface, accessibility

In the Stack Snippets interface, links that are `.snippet-result a` - which is to say

- the `.popout-code a.snippet-expand-link` "Expand snippet" link seen at the start and "Return to post" link seen after clicking "Expand snippet",
- the `.popout a` "Full page" link seen after clicking "Run code snippet",
- and the `.popin a` "Close" button on seen after clicking "Full page"

can't be selected with the `tab` key.

Compare them to the `button.btn-clear` "Hide results" link seen after clicking "Run code snippet", which is `tab`-selectable.

This is reproducible in the latest Chrome, FF, and ([with tab link navigation turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1914496/1241736)) Safari.

As far as I've noticed, every other visible clickable thing on an SO page is `tab`-selectable. Can we tweak these links so they are too?